# _co.openSignup is not a function

Tags: angular

I am trying to show model which is defined in header.component.ts and I want to show that model in another component. I am new to angular help me out with this.

HTML:

```
<a (click)="openSignup()" class="btn btn-success text-white">signup</a>
```

Here is my **header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';
import { Router }      from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../admin/services/auth.service';

import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';



@Component({
 selector: 'app-header',
 templateUrl: './header.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})

export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, public aS:AuthService, public router: Router, public cokkie:CookieService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openSignup(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(SignupDialog, {
      width: '500px',
      data: { name: "test" }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
     console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
  }
}
```

And **signup-dialog.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'signup-dialog',
  templateUrl: 'signup-dialog.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class SignupDialog {

  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<SignupDialog>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

   onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
   }
}
```

I want to open this model in another component and I am getting this error `_co.openSignup is not a function`

Comment: Show the HTML Code

Comment: Please can you show HTML code how are you trying to open the `dialog` ?

Comment: <a (click)="openSignup()" class="btn btn-success text-white">signup</a>

Comment: and all TS Code

Comment: Working fine here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1pethv

Comment: @AjayNamdev HTML Code will be helpful

Comment: thanks @prashant pimpale your link was very helpfull to sort this out.

Comment: @AjayNamdev I didn't do anything btw you are welcome